# Reverse Port Forward using libssh2 on iOS

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, ssh, libssh2

I'm looking for some example code of a reverse port forward on iOS using libssh2. Here's a close example:

[Example code of libssh2 being used for port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580750/example-code-of-libssh2-being-used-for-port-forwarding)

But I'd like it to be tailored to iOS and objective-C if possible. Straight C is fine too. I'm wary of the socket and FD code, and would rather have a robust solution than the one I'm hacking up. I've tried RTFMing libssh2 for a while, but it ends up being just RTF Code... and I'm not confident enough in my C code to do this networking part.

EDIT: bounty for a working implementation of ssh with port forwarding on iOS 4.3 (e.g. iphone4, ipad2), doesn't need to be `libssh2` in specific.

Comment: Also, I didn't mean to be so demanding :) I plan on offering a bounty, as this seems to be a very difficult thing to find!

Comment: The code snippet that is provided in the link you posted, is hardly "C++" Just remove the usage of std::*, and you should have a perfectly usable C version. However, remember to test it, before using it. I don't see how this whole exercise is useful to other programmers as a question though (hence the downvote)

Comment: That's what I've been trying but the code fragment doesn't seem to work.  I just replaced the boost:: yields with some timeouts etc.  There's also some proprietary windows calls in there too.

Comment: Also, if you scour libssh2's mailing list, this question has been asked a whole heap of times.  If posting example code to stack overflow isn't useful, than perhaps I'm missing the purpose of this site.

Comment: I think you are indeed missing the point of this site. It's not a place where you just ask for code samples regarding x or y; it's more of a share your efforts and have others criticize and correct them.

Comment: That might be your purpose (and I can respect that), but for me this site is about communicating with other developers to solve problems. This is a problem, and i'm asking for help.  The code is almost exactly like the other question i've referenced.  Perhaps you could explain how this question could be better worded?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it's fairly straightforward to migrate the putty source http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ to ios ...

Comment: Any links to an ongoing effort?  Googling provides nothing for me.  Also, I was not aware that putty had a library... the source code is for the entire binary (much like openssh).

Comment: I'm going to clean it up and github it when i get a chance

Comment: Do you need any help? If you post it I can start cleaning it up and poking at it.